# font-style in @font-face doesn't work with local font

Tags: css, font-face

For the `<i>` tag, I want **English characters to show as italic, non-English characters to show as normal**.

This is my CSS.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyCustomFont;
  src: local(Kaiti);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: MyCustomFont; 
  font-style:italic;
  unicode-range: U+00-024F; 
  src: local(Arial);
}

i {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

The actual result is

[image: The English characters are not Arial italic, while the non-English characters are in Kaiti.]

The non-English characters are in Kaiti normak, which is correct, but the English characters are not Arial italic. Did I miss anything?

I'm using Chrome 54.0.

Comment: your first two selectors seem to be the same. @font-face

Answer (score 0):

Set a fallback font for `i`:

```
i {
  font-family: MyCustomFont, Arial, serif;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to force by inserting "!import;" at the end of css element ?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:
This is your HTML:

```
<i>食english</i>
```

in order to assign specific css attributes to part of that text you need to enclose it in a different element. For example:

```
<i>食<span>english</span></i>
```

Now you can reference that element (span in this case) in the css:

```
span {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

The attribute you are looking for is font-style:italic;
The [HTML em element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_em.asp) renders as italic (the browser already applies the above style) as far as i know. So you could go with:

```
<i>食<em>english</em></i>
```

and avoid applying the styling (as the browser does it directly).

I hope it helps.

---

**Original**:

If I understood the question correctly you are missing the italic styling:

```
i {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: MyCustomFont;
  src: local(Kaiti);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: MyCustomFont; 
  font-style:italic;
  unicode-range: U+00-024F; 
  src: local(Arial);
}

i {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<span>食<i>english</i></span>
```

Comment: No, my HTML is `<i>食english</i>`，食 should be Kaiti normal, english should be Arial italic.

Comment: Well in that case you need to assign a different HTML element to either the english or the non-english.

Comment: Did you mean font-style in `@font-face` is unable to archive that? Can you explain what font-style does in `@font-face`?

Comment: There is no problem with @font-face. If you want to assign italic css attribute you need to enclose that text in a different element.